# How to set the position of Actor subclass ignoring the position in draw method

Tags: java, android, libgdx, stage

I have this class:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor{
TextureRegion region;

public MyActor(TextureRegion region)
{
    this.region = region;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(region, 0, 0);
}

}
```

And I make use of it here like this:

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {

Stage stage;
MyActor myActor;

@Override
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(0, 0, false);
    myActor = new MyActor(new TextureRegion(new Texture(
            Gdx.files.internal("texture.png"))));

    myActor.setPosition(200, 50);
    stage.addActor(myActor);

}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
}
```

In the `MyActor` class I set the position of the actor to `(0, 0)`. I just used this as some kind of default as I want to be able to change its position before it's actually drawn on the stage. The reason is I have a few `MyActor` objects and I want to draw them all on the stage but at different positions.

So I did `myActor.setPosition(200, 50);`, but it didn't work.

My question: How can I draw `myActor` on the stage with position other than what is set in `draw(Batch, float)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.draw(region, 0, 0);
}
```

Remove the `super.draw` call here. Right now it shouldn't do anything, if it would do anything, it will probably cause problems.

Furthermore, you complained, that your actor position is not used. That's because you didn't use it.

Try something like this instead:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.draw(region, getX(), getY());
}
```

Comment: but why should we use getX(), getY() inside Actor? I mean why do we need actor at all if we still have to calculate positions based on some outer values..

Comment: `Actor` is part of Scene2D, which is a scene graph. Every node in a scene graph has a local coordinate system relative to its parent. So getX() and getY() return the *local* coordinates. The resulting position is based on outer values, but you don't have to care about that. The scenegraph will take care of that for you. If you do not have a hierarchical structure of entities in your scene, there's nearly no advantage though. Besides being able to register EventListeners to handle clicks and such.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending `Actor` you could extend `Image`, which is a subclass of `Actor`. `Image` allready holds a `Drawable` (you can use your `TextureRegion` in the constructor of `TextureRegionDrawable`). Then in your `Image`-subclass you can override `draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)`, do some controlls if necessary and call `suoer.draw(batch, parentAlpha)` and there your `Actor` will be drawn at the right `position`, `rotation`, `scale`...

**EDIT:** `Image` is a subclass of `Widget`. `Widget` itself extends `Actor`.
From LibGDX Api:

> Displays a Drawable, scaled various way within the widgets bounds. The
>   preferred size is the min size of the drawable. Only when using a
>   TextureRegionDrawable will the actor's scale, rotation, and origin be
>   used when drawing.

So if you use a TextureRegionDrawable it will also handle the rotation, scale and origin you set to your `Actor`, if you need that. It has everything that `Actor` class has and **MORE**

**Another EDIT:** As you said you have to store other data you can simply have your `MyActor extends Image`. In your `MyActor` you can store all the Data you need, but you don't need to store the Image anymore and you don't have to take care about drawing anymore. So this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason for the downvote, so i can improve my answer and help others. Thanks

Comment: I can't extend image because MyActor class isn't only an image.

Comment: Image has everything that Actor does and more. So if you extend Actor and store a TextureRegion in it you have more or less the same as directly extending Image.

Comment: What I mean is I only showed `TextureRegion` in the example I showed above, but in my actual code `MyActor` also stores a `String`.

Comment: You can have ´MyActor´ extends ´Image´ and store ONLY the ´String´. The Drawable is stored in the superclass Image allready. And you don't have to take care about drawing anymore, if you set the position and everything else correct.

Comment: @noone's is working for me right now. I'll try yours too and see which is easier for me to work with.

Comment: Ofc his solution is working. Mine is the same, but you just don't need to store your Drawable yourself :) But if this works for you as well its fine.

Comment: @NiiLaryea But did you understand the advantage of `Image` over `Actor`?

Comment: @NiiLaryea good. But in my opinion it has also a disadvantage, because i don't like the drawables that much. I like TextureRegions more but the Image class does the drawing verry well. if you understood that you can also remove the downvote if it was you :P If you stil don't like my answer please tell me why and i will improve it.